# Still unresolved: how to calculate price change (using prices from DIFFERENT dates) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Consider the following table:

```
sp100_id  _date        open  close  bullishness
-----------------------------------------------
1         2011-03-14   100   110    2.23
1         2011-03-15   115   100    1.00
1         2011-03-16   110   110    0.85
2         2011-03-14    90    85    0.99
2         2011-03-15    95    90    0.30
2         2011-03-16    92   100    4.66
3         2011-03-14   200   220    1.50
3         2011-03-15   250   210    1.75
3         2011-03-16   200   150    0.80
```

I want to calculate the `% return` and `bullishness` for each stock between `2011-03-14` and  `2011-03-16`, rank them by `% return` DESC, and the return `sp100_id`, `% return` and `average bullishness`. I thought the following query would do the trick:

```
SELECT 
  sp100_id, 
  AVG(bullishness) as bullishness, 
  ((`close`-`open`) / `open`) as return_pct   
FROM
  stocks 
WHERE _date = BETWEEN '2011-03-14' AND '2011-03-16' 
ORDER BY return_pct DESC
```

However, it always just seems to return just one row. The expected output was however:

```
sp100_id return_pct                average bullishness
-----------------------------------------------------------
3        (150-200)/200 = -0.250   (1.50+1.75+0.80)/3 = 4.05
2        (100-90)/90   =  0.110   (0.99+0.30+4.66)/3 = 1.98
1        (110-100)/100 =  0.100   (2.23+1.00+0.85)/3 = 4.08
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you use `GROUP BY 1`?

Answer (score 3):

You must use `GROUP BY`in your query:

```
SELECT 
  sp100_id, 
  AVG(bullishness) as bullishness, 
  (((SELECT `close` FROM stocks s2
   WHERE s2.sp100_id=s1.sp100_id ORDER BY _date DESC LIMIT 1)
    -(SELECT `open` FROM stocks s3
   WHERE s3.sp100_id=s1.sp100_id ORDER BY _date ASC LIMIT 1)) / 
     (SELECT `open` FROM stocks s3
   WHERE s3.sp100_id=s1.sp100_id ORDER BY _date ASC LIMIT 1)) as return_pct
FROM
  stocks s1
WHERE _date BETWEEN '2011-03-14' AND '2011-03-16' 
GROUP BY sp100_id
ORDER BY return_pct DESC
```

Without `GROUP BY`, it returns only one result row because `AVG` groups all records together.

I fixed the computation of return_pct using subqueries with `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1`.

Documentation: [GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html)

[SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7396f/15)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried running your query to see what the output is, but it doesn't run on SQLFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7396f/1. Second, are you sure it outputs the the correct `return_pct`? In my query, it calculated `return_pct` only by using the `open` and `close` values from `2011-03-16` but I see you're doing something with `SUM` that would perhaps fix that?

Comment: I removed the `=` sign just before `BETWEEN`, it fixes the syntax error and now runs fine. See this [updated sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7396f/7)

Comment: It still doesn't work as expected. The query should take the `open` price of the first date (`2011-03-14`) and the `close` price of the second date (`2011-03-16`). I have changed the SQLFiddle `close` price for company 3 on `2011-03-16` into `150` (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81cbf/1). Now, the query should return `(150-200)/200=-0.25` but it returns `0.1` because `MIN/MAX` make it calculate `(220-200)/200`. Any ideas? I **always** just need the `open` price for the first date and the `close` price for the second date to perform the calculation with. Thanks for your help so far, BTW :-)

Comment: With the explanation provided in your comment, I understood at last which computation has to be done. I updated again my answer and added an SQLfiddle.

Comment: This almost works, thanks. But when I change `BETWEEN '2011-03-14' AND '2011-03-16'` into `BETWEEN '2011-03-14' AND '2011-03-15'` (so between the 14th and 15th), the query still takes the `close` values from the 16th and I don't understand why. Please see here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7396f/16 and notice that only the `bullsihness` values change when you change the end date from `2011-03-16` to `2011-03-15`. Any idea what goes wrong?

Comment: Have a look to this [SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7396f/33). Is it what you want?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15689/discussion-between-jocelyn-and-pr0no)